# How to automount sshfs?

Tags: ssh, fstab, automounting, sshfs

I am trying to auto mount a remote resource through `sshfs` but is not working for me. I have read all of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29250/sshfs-always-asking-for-password-in-fstab), [this](https://superuser.com/questions/669287/automount-sshfs-using-fstab-without-mount-a), [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSHFS) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/326977/sshfs-is-not-mounting-automatically-at-boot-despite-etc-fstab-configuration) before ask to see if I can get the solution for my issue but it didn't work.

So here is what I have done so far:

- Added the following line to `/etc/fstab`:

  ```
  <username>@remote_host_ip_address:remote_path host_path fuse.sshfs delay_connect,_netdev,user,idmap=user,transform_symlinks,identityfile=/home/<username>/.ssh/id_rsa,allow_other,default_permissions,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
  ```
- I have ssh into the remote host once so it gets added to the `/home/<username>/.ssh/know_hosts` file. I have checked after and the remote host is there
- I have run the command `sudo mount -a`

When I change directory and check the local path something goes wrong since I can not `cd` into it and it looks like:

[image]

What I am doing wrong here? What I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using system-wide `/etc/fstab`, I suggest using [afuse](https://github.com/pcarrier/afuse/). It's mentioned in passing in the Arch wiki you link, but it's also included in Fedora. This runs in your user session and can therefore either use `ssh-agent` or prompt for a password.

It also will only mount on demand, and can be configured to unmount after a timeout, which is particularly valuable if your network isn't perfectly solid.

```
afuse -o intr -o timeout=300 \
  -o mount_template='sshfs -o intr -o follow_symlinks -o reconnect <username>@<remote_host_ip_address>:<remote_path>:%r %m' \
  -o unmount_template='fusermount -u -z %m' \
  ~/<localmount>
```

... making sure to replace the `<things in brackets>` with your local options. The afuse docs give a few other options that you can use - I like `-o populate_root_command`, but it's not necessary.

There are a number of different ways to run this automatically on login; it depends on your desktop environment, but basically you'd have to add the afuse line to autostart like any other such command.

Comment: Ok, but `afuse` command can not be used on boot, right? If can be used can you add the proper line to your answer?

Comment: Do you _need_ it to be available on boot? Why?

Comment: Well the idea is not to run the command all the time, for example let's said I run the command once, then for some X reason the computer restart and I need to login again, I would like to have the shared folder mount by default but anyway if this is not possible then what's the right command for mount the shared folder using `afuse`? The example on the Wiki link is not so helpful

Comment: Afuse will mount the sshfs filesystem automatically _whenever you access it_. I'll add some details.

Comment: afuse hasn't been updated in 7 years

Comment: @crypdick Concerning, but it still works for me.