# How to automount SSHFS shares for a user upon login?

Tags: pam, automounting, sshfs, autofs

My question is how to mount SSHFS shares ***as the user*** (not root) upon demand or upon user login using only tools that are in my distro's core repos. I'm using Arch. I don't mind writing a small script, if required. I would also like the same shares unmounted after the user logs out.

Background: I have checked other similar questions and did not find a suitable answer. Examples:

- [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/311409/15010) recommends afuse, which is apparently defunct now. (It's website is offline, and I don't find afuse in the Arch repos.)
- [This one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/308049/15010) also recommends afuse.

Furthermore, the [automounting section of the SSHFS Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSHFS#Automounting) has some issues. It is marked as out of date. And it uses a method that mounts the SSHFS shares as **root**, which then requires the use of the `allow_other` mount option. But that combination exposes the following bug:

> If you intend to use the allow_other mount options, be aware that FUSE
>   has an [unresolved security
>   bug](https://github.com/libfuse/libfuse/issues/15): if the
>   default_permissions mount option is not used, the results of the first
>   permission check performed by the file system for a directory entry
>   will be re-used for subsequent accesses as long as the inode of the
>   accessed entry is present in the kernel cache - even if the
>   permissions have since changed, and even if the subsequent access is
>   made by a different user. This is of little concern if the filesystem
>   is accessible only to the mounting user (which has full access to the
>   filesystem anyway), but becomes a security issue when other users are
>   allowed to access the filesystem (since they can exploit this to
>   perform operations on the filesystem that they do not actually have
>   permissions for).

A work-around for that bug is to use **default_permissions** with allow_other, but default_permissions doesn't support ACL's (and this combination *may* also lead to other permissions-related issues in my experience).

More details:

I wish to have the mounts performed by the regular user (when the user logs in or on demand) **without** using either default_permissions or allow_other. (Preliminary testing indicates that this method results in the permissions working as expected.) **UPDATE**: No, I was wrong. Permissions remain problematic when the directory is owned by another user and group permissions are used to grant access. In that case access is improperly denied. I think the correct answer may be: DO NOT USE SSHFS in situations like mine.

I also do not want to use any marginal packages or even packages from the AUR.

I have seen a suggestion that `pam_exec.so` might be a solution, but I have not seen any detailed examples of how this would be configured for automounting shares for each user. Also, if I use this method, I would like to unmount the same shares when the user logs out.

Another option may be AutoFS. However, once again the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Autofs) for this topic uses an example that requires root. It even has "**As root**" in bold. (The wiki page also has an open dispute on that issue. I would prefer a non-ambiguous or authoritative answer regarding how to do this.)

I don't want the solution limited to GUI login. Any automounting (at login or on demand) should be effective in the DE, a virtual console or (hopefully) even an SSH login.

Comment: Afuse is not dead. It works well&daily, [Here is the Arch Package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/afuse/). If you can use this official package, then your Q has the [same answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/528699/127903) as that [Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/294965/integration-of-afuse-user-level-automounter-with-sshfs-as-a-systemd-service-spaw). Oh, i just noticed, that Arch only got the afuse package a month after your Q. Debian&Co have had it for years.